# Missing Template Arguments

Tags: c++, templates

This is part of a homework assignment, but I've reduced the problem as far as possible. The code presented doesn't really do anything, just create some objects, so I am down to pure language issues.

I think my question is: Is it possible for a template class to create another class of the same template type?

The assignment is to have a main.cc as following:

```cpp
#include "linkedlist.hh"

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> aList;
    ListIterator elements = aList.iterator(); // if commented out, then no error
}
```

I have the following for linkedlist.hh:

```cpp
template <typename T> class LinkedList;
template <typename T> class ListIterator;

template <typename T>
    class LinkedList {
    public:
    ListIterator<T> iterator();
};

template <typename T>
    ListIterator<T> LinkedList<T>::iterator() {
    return new ListIterator<T>;
}

template <typename T>
    class ListIterator {
};
```

Which give the following error with g++-4.6:

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:6:18: error: missing template arguments before ‘elements’
main.cc:6:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘elements’
```

And a similar error with clang++-2.9:

```
main.cc:6:5: error: cannot refer to class template 'ListIterator' without a
      template argument list
    ListIterator elements = list.iterator();
    ^
In file included from main.cc:1:
./linkedlist.hh:16:11: note: template is declared here
    class ListIterator {
```

---

### UPDATE: Yes if I could change main.cc, then I could do the following, but I don't think that is what the assignment is.

main.cc

```cpp
#include "linkedlist.hh"

int main()
{
    LinkedList<int> aList;
    ListIterator<int> elements = aList.iterator();
}
```

and linkedlist.hh

```cpp
template <typename T> class LinkedList;
template <typename T> class ListIterator;

template <typename T>
    class LinkedList {
    public:
    ListIterator<T> iterator();
};

template <typename T>
    ListIterator<T> LinkedList<T>::iterator() {
    ListIterator<T> anIterator;
    return anIterator;
}

template <typename T>
    class ListIterator {
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by a class creating another class?  One class can have another class nested inside of it.  One class can reference another class.  It isn't clear how your example relates to what you are trying to accomplish.  The error is just because you haven't specified the template parameter.  Iterators are often nested classes, so maybe you are wanting LinkedList<T>::Iterator.

Comment: I am referring to `ListIterator elements = aList.iterator();`        aList.iterator() returns an object of type ListIterator. Is it possible for aList to know its own template type and create the proper ListIterator?

Comment: aList.iterator() is creating an object of the proper type -- that isn't the issue.

Comment: You could create a generic ListIterator class that had a templated constructor so that it could accept an iterator of any type.  Could that be what is wanted?

Comment: Are there any other requirements than that the given main.cc compiles?

Comment: There will be other requirements for the ListIterator class (implement `++`, `=` and `atEnd()` but for now, I just want to create the objects. A generic ListIterator sounds interesting if it could access any type. Looking this up now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be `ListIterator<int>`?

Comment: Yes. I could make it work using that method, but that is not what the professor asked for (though perhaps he made a mistake?). He wants what I gave in main.cc. I will ask the prof. about the version I will give below, but to answer my question, I suppose the answer is "NO - a template class cannot create another template class"?

Comment: @Jeremiah: The class teamplte _does_ instantiate another class template. The problem is that you then try to assign the properly typed return value to `ListIterator elements`. That declaration just does not make sense. And yes, the professor made a mistake. `ListIterator<T>::operator*()` has to return a `T&`. If `ListIterator` isn't a template, it can't have a proper `operator*` because you can't write a return type.

Answer (score 0):

`ListIterator` is a template, obviously you have to give it a template parameter. Try `ListIterator<int>`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could implement a generic iterator that could do some basic operations on the iterator for a list of any type of elements, but it would be unusual.

```
struct ListIteratorBase {
  virtual void advance() = 0;
  virtual bool atEnd() const = 0;
  virtual ~ListIteratorBase() { }
};

template <typename T>
struct BasicListIterator : ListIteratorBase {
  virtual void advance(); // implement this
  virtual bool atEnd() const;  // and this
  T value() const; // and this
};

struct ListIterator {
  template <typename T> ListIterator(BasicListIterator<T> &iter)
  : iter_ptr(new BasicListIterator<T>(iter))
  {
  }

  ~ListIterator() { delete iter_ptr; }

  void operator++() { iter_ptr->advance(); }
  bool atEnd() const { return iter_ptr->atEnd(); }

  // Method to get the value for a particular type.  It is up to the caller to
  // make sure the type is right at runtime.
  template <typename T>
  T get<>() const
  {
    BasicListIterator<T> *p = dynamic_cast<BasicListIterator<T> *>(iter_ptr);
    assert(p);
    return p->value();
  }

  ~ListIterator() { delete iter_ptr; }

  ListIteratorBase *iter_ptr;
};
```

You would then need

```
template <typename T>
BasicListIterator<T> LinkedList<T>::iterator() { ... }
```

Comment: For it to be more usual, could you demonstrate how you dereference the iterator? :) - As to factoring non-type-dependent code into a non-template base class, that's not a very unusual optimization, except that the base class will be rather useless to the end user and it is done without virtual functions.

Comment: I added a templated get() method.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, in C++11,  **auto** directive was added

see [Type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Type_inference)

Answer (score 0):

Rename ListIterator and add `typedef MyListIterator<int> ListIterator;` to the end of the header. Then the main code will work unmodified.

This is just a trick to make this particular given code work. You can't make a standard library compliant iterator that is not a template or template-dependent. If you don't have to make a standard library compliant iterator, then you can employ a technique called type erasure (Vaughn Cato's answer), but that's a rather advanced topic.